# Session gone after multiple refreshes or after a couple of minutes in LARAVEL 5

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5, session-variables

As the title said, I have a problem with my Session variables, I already stored the details during log-in. However, after a couple of refreshes or navigation on the site I lose all of my Session variables.

Session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'), 
'lifetime' => 999, 
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

and my Authenticate controller.

```
public function authenticate(){ 
 $username = Input::get('username'); 
 $password = Input::get('password');

if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    // Store user data
    $this->storeSessionData();
    return redirect('dashboard');   
}
else{
    return 
        redirect()->back()->with('message', array('username' => $username));
   }
}

public function storeSessionData(){
// Retrieves the authenticated user
$user = Auth::user();
// Set details to session.
Session::put('firstname', $user->first_name);
Session::put('lastname',  $user->last_name);
Session::put('usertype',  $user->user_type); 
Session::put('image',     $user->image);
Session::put('mac',       ServerAddress::MACADDRESS());
}

 public function logout(){
//Logs user out
Auth::logout();

//Clears history
Session::flush();

//redirect back to login
return redirect('login');
}
```

Comment: You don't need to store `User Data` instead you can always use `auth()->user()->field_name` and did you mean automatic log out after a couple of minutes?

Comment: Yes something like that.. I var_dump(Session::get()) and all of the data have been flushed

Comment: use Session::all() for get all session data...!!!